# PHP loops through an definitely empty array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

We use a model that always returns arrays. It never returns an object, null, 0, false or something else. Now, I found a fatal error. PHP loops through an empty array. How is that possible?

```
var_dump($arrProduct); //prints array > empty
foreach($arrProduct as $Product){
    var_dump($Product); //null
    $name = $Product->getTitle(); //my Exception

}
```

Casting to array does not help. I con't test if the array contains values because this model is used on several 100 lines.

Might this be a PHP setting issue or a cache issue?

Comment: simply add `if (!empty($arrProduct)`

Comment: are you using short tags in your code?

Comment: It's not empty!  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b55d917d6dcefe35b35356b6bf9e10c400671e36 If it was it wouldn't execute the `foreach`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes its empty how can you say It's not empty?

Comment: No it's not as can be seen in the link.  Also, post the *"real"* `var_dump()` output.

Comment: @AbraCadaver There are two `var_dump` see before loop `var_dump($arrProduct); //prints array > empty`

Comment: `array > empty` is not valid output of `var_dump()`.

Comment: because empty foreach would return a notice not fatal error

Comment: Looping through an empty array doesn't result in a fatal error (or any kind of error). What's the exact message from PHP?

Comment: Please post your error message

Comment: `var_dump($arrProduct);`

Comment: The fatal error is that it calls an method from null. But in my opinion it should not even start a single loop when the array is empoty.

Comment: Could you post the actual error? literally copy and paste the error.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your array is not empty, but it contains `NULL`s.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see the error from outside my company. But the error says just that it calls getTitle() from null. That's not our problem here.

Comment: Yeah, that might be possible. It seems var_dump interprets array(NULL) as an empty array but foreach doesn't. Interesting.

Comment: As you have been told several times, var_dump() would never produce the output `array > empty`, so your interpretation that var_dump thinks your array is empty is still faulty.

Comment: The exact var_dump is, as I wrote below array (size=0)
  empty

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the solutions: reason:

there was a semikolon and the end of the line after foreach

```
foreach($arrProduct as $Product){                                             ;
```

Nobody noticed it :-)

The funny thing is, that this is fully valid code.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($arrProduct && is_array($arrProduct)) {
    foreach($arrProduct as $Product){
        var_dump($Product); //null
        $name = $Product->getTitle(); //my Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Its clear that I can avoid this error by using if. But the problem is that I used this model so often that its impossible to change every foreach. And why does this PHP test suite return array(0); on our server with PHP 5.4.x it says array { empty }

Comment: how can you avoid this fatal error if you don't verify the content of your $arrProduct ?

Comment: Here some server information: Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u2

Comment: Here's the exact var_dump output.
array (size=0)
  empty